# Replace all multiple double forward slashes with single forward slash

Tags: regex, perl

I have been searching the forum and have found many examples of replacing multiple backslashes with single backslashes. However, modifying them with my forward slashes case, none of them work.

I have the following string to modify

```
$workdir='//dir1///dir2/////dir3///dir4///' ;
```

Where, in general, the number of forward slashes between each 'dirx' can be greater or equal to 1.

I need to apply one or more regex's to $workdir so the result is:

```
$workdir='/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4' ;
```

I can achieve the result with the following piece of code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $workdir='//dir1///dir2/////dir3///dir4///' ;
print $workdir . "\n";
my $NERROR1=0;
my $workdir_Prev=$workdir;
while($NERROR1==0){
    $workdir =~ s/\/\//\//g;
    if($workdir eq $workdir_Prev){
        $NERROR1=1;
    } else {
        $workdir_Prev=$workdir;
    }
}
    
$NERROR1=0;
$workdir_Prev=$workdir;
while($NERROR1==0){
    $workdir =~ s/\/$//g;
    if($workdir eq $workdir_Prev){
        $NERROR1=1;
    } else {
        $workdir_Prev=$workdir;
    }
}
print $workdir . "\n";
```

Is there a more compact way of doing this?

I could replace all my forward slashes with backslashes, then run the code on the forum that deals with multiple backslashes. Finally I could convert the backslashes back to forward slashes. However, much like my solution above, this seems a rather cumbersome solution.

Comment: I don't know Perl but a regex replace with the PCRE engine is pretty easy: https://regex101.com/r/5wS40e/1

Comment: `$foo =~ s!/{2,}!/!g;` (replace each run of 2 or more slashes with a single slash)

Comment: You can replace matches of the regular expression `/(?=/|$)` with an empty string.  The expression reads, "Match a forward slash when it is followed by a forward slash or the end of the string." `(?=...)` denotes a *positive lookahead*, an assertion that must satisfied but does not form part of the match that is returned. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXaJnj/1).

Comment: A one liner! Excellent! Many thanks @CarySwoveland. An elegant solution.

Comment: Regarding my suggestion above, `/+(?=/|$)` is probably a little more efficient.

Comment: Once again, many thanks @CarySwoveland. For anyone interested, the perl syntax I used is: `$workdir =~ s/\/+(?=\/|$)//g;`

Comment: @CarySwoveland That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's a local path (as opposed to a URL or a path for a different OS), I suggest the following:

```perl
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );

$workdir = canonpath( $workdir );
```

This also handles `foo/./bar` ⇒ `foo/bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-whitespace delimiter may replace the slashes within `s/search/replace/`, so the substitute could be changed to `s=//+=/=g` to replace all multiples with a single. Similarly `s=/+$==` will replace the final slashes. I do not see a way of combining them into one substitiute.

Comment: Many thanks to all with your quick responses. The simplest and most compact solution seems to be the regex `$workdir =~ s/\/+/\//g;` followed by `$workdir =~ s/\/+$//g;`

Comment: `$` should be `\z`. (But that only matters if you have a file whose name is a line feed.)

Comment: Good point! Thanks @ikegami